# Javascript onclick not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, onclick

I cannot figure out why the following code works in IE and in Firefox on a different computer but on my laptop.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled both Firefox and java.
Each section has a Acknowledge and Delete button when clicked either sets the acknowledge or deletes the alarm.
Works fine in IE, and a copy of Firefox on a different computer.

On the problem computer the screen flashes when the button is clicked but the alarm is neither clear or acknowledged.
No errors are thrown in apache2 logs.

It basically passes three variables to another php page that updates a sql table.
No errors are thrown in sql either.

Just a flash of the screen and no change on problem computer.
Works fine in IE on same computer.

```
if ($_SESSION['pH1_Low_Alarm'] > 0) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $_SESSION['pH1_Low_Time'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>pH1 Low</td>";
    if ($_SESSION['pH1_Low_Alarm'] == 1) {
        echo "<td>Unacknowledged</td>";
        echo "<td></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"alarmname_ack_id\" id=\"alarmname_ack_id\" value=\"Acknowledge\" onclick=\"alarm_sql('pH1','Low_Alarm',3)\" /></td>";
    }
    if ($_SESSION['pH1_Low_Alarm'] == 2) {
        echo "<td>Unacknowledged</td>";
        echo "<td align=\"center\"><img src=\"img/email.png\" /></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"alarmname_ack_id\" id=\"alarmname_ack_id\" value=\"Acknowledge\" onclick=\"alarm_sql('pH1','Low_Alarm',4)\" /></td>";
    }
    if ($_SESSION['pH1_Low_Alarm'] == 3) {
        echo "<td>Acknowledged</td>";
        echo "<td></td>";
        echo "<td></td>";
    }
    if ($_SESSION['pH1_Low_Alarm'] == 4) {
        echo "<td>Acknowledged</td>";
        echo "<td align=\"center\"><img src=\"img/email.png\" /></td>";
        echo "<td></td>";
    }
    echo "<td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"alarmname_ack_id\" id=\"alarmname_ack_id\" value=\"Delete\" onclick=\"alarm_sql('pH1','Low_Alarm',0)\" /></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

The function being called by the onclick event

```
function alarm_sql(sensorname, alarmname, alarmvalue) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{   // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    alarm_php_string = new String;
    alarm_php_string = "sql/sql_alarm_set.php?sensorname=" + sensorname + "&alarmname=" + alarmname + "&alarmvalue=" + alarmvalue;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",alarm_php_string,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    sleep(500);
    document.location.reload(true);
}
```

UPDATE

If i right click on the acknowledge or delete button and select Inspect Element:

Then in the resulting window under debugger, I place a breakpoint at the beginning of the function above just after the var declaration.
I can then after clicking the button Single step through the code which actually works this way.
Not sure what that means when a single step works but without the breakpoints the code fails.

This is what shows in the console after clicking the acknowledge button when it doesn't work.

```
GET 
http://192.168.1.200/yieldbuddy/www/alarms.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 16ms]
GET 
http://192.168.1.200/yieldbuddy/www/img/background.png [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 11ms]
GET 
http://192.168.1.200/yieldbuddy/www/img/banner.png [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 16ms]
GET 
http://192.168.1.200/yieldbuddy/www/img/email.png
```

It appears to be a issue with my Window7 installation on the laptop. I can run this code without issue on every other computer in the house but this one. All the other computers after upgrading to Firefox 48 still run the code without problem. Whatever is causing it happens even after removing and reinstalling both firefox and java. Looks like i am heading to a complete operation system fresh install on the problem computer.

Comment: Without the breakpoints do you get any errors in Firefox's console? Also, why are you calling `.reload()` from code that runs *before* the Ajax response is received? That could be why adding breakpoints fixes things. (And as an aside that may or may not be relevant, whatever `sleep(500);` does is *not* how to implement a delay in JS. Use `setTimeout()`.)

Comment: You use `alarmname_ack_id` (your "acknowledge button") muliple times as an `id`==> 1st: fail. You should consider the single quote set as an alternative to always escape `"`. ==> 2nd... As advise. QUESTION: Where is your `$("#alarmname_ack_id").click()` handler ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was corrected with the following action in Firefox 48.

Menu/options/advanced/network/connection - settings

Change the proxy setting from

use system proxy

to

No proxy

Not sure of the cause but this corrected the issue on the problem computer the webpage works as expected after the change.